# How to set Status bar background color iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

iOS 6 look...

[image]

Same way i would like to display status bar in iOS 7 like

see this

[image]

but My actual output (Overlap)

i have tried following logic

```
open your info.plist and set "View controller-based status bar appearance" = NO
```

it's not working in my code,,,

Comment: @swt- their are lots of questions on SO, have u searched

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to do 2 things. First is to open your `info.plist` and set `"View controller-based status bar appearance" = NO`

And the second is to add this lines to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{   
    self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];     

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 0,self.window.frame.size.width-20,self.window.frame.size.height);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    } else
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: my apps run in Landscape mode. but your code appear black bar right and left side

Comment: Updated an answer to support both orientations.

Comment: but working fine... but when i rotate screen that was not changing based on screen orientation

Comment: You should register for statusbarorientationchanged notification and use the same code over there. I can not write the app instead of you, I already gave you an answer, so you should get it's point and use it accordingly to your needs.

Comment: actually the key you have to add to info.plist is:
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO

Answer (score 9):

Read this article: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]  

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5)];
```

Comment: Excellent link for those devs putting images on their UINavigationBar.

Comment: Sadly didn't do much for my iPad application. Good link though

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me, storyboard, ios7. Added that line to AppDelegate didFinishLaunching

Answer (score 0):

Move  your frame 20 pixels down. You can try writing this in your ViewWillappear or DidAppear

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = 20;

if (self.view.frame.size.height == 1024 ||   self.view.frame.size.height == 768)
{
    frame.size.height -= 20;
}
self.view.frame = frame;
```

Now set background color of window to black in applicationDidFinishLaunching and set statusbar font to be white (StatusBarContentLight)

Remember what i am suggesting is not perfect solution but a fix that will work nicely. Also use same code when app changes its orientation (ShouldAutorotate)