# Changing IOS7 statusbar content color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

Hi I am developing small IOS application in which I am using simple one window with navigation controller. What I want to do is change status bar colour to white. For that I did following things.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

It works fine.[image]

But now I don't want navigation bar and I hide it `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

It removes navigation bar but it is not applying that white colour theme to my status bar. It again turn to black.

[image]

I don't want navigation bar but I want to change status bar content to white. How to do this. Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: Android? looks like iOS to mee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

Also, change the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in your PLIST file to `NO`.

*NOTE:* This question has been asked before. Please research a little more for questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065098/status-bar-text-color-ios-7).

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick replay. this solution is not working for me. Because I am hiding navigation bar. If I have navigation bar visible then it works fine. But if i hide it then its not working. Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: In Plist file I put UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO and in appdelegate file I put above code

Comment: My show navigation bar property is uncheck in storyboard. Because I don't want navigation bar.

Comment: This is peculiar. What color is the status bar text in your case ?

Comment: Add it in the first view controller of your application's `viewWillAppear`, instead of appDelegate. Try this and tell if it's working.

Comment: But I tried It in another project its not working for that one. I set Plist attribute. Then I set all the values like I said before. But still showing same problem. It's works for another project. Am I doing some thing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a `UIView` with color on status bar, check this:

```
UIView *temporaryStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]];
temporaryStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.window addSubview:temporaryStatusBar];
```

Comment: I tried It. It will change only background colour for status bar but will not change text colour to white.

Comment: for the text color you need to change the status bar style to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
this style will give u a white color text

Comment: Yeah i tried that as well It working fine if my navigation bar is not hidden. But If hide navigation bar then it will not work. Please read question carefully.

Comment: i just edited the answer, u can check it now and it's working cause i tested this code also while the navigationBar is hidden :)

Comment: this is my code, u can add this code in the AppDelegate after the didFinishLunching or u can use it in your RootViewController in the viewDidLoad!! where do use this code? and what's not working for u, the text color or the status bar color ???

Comment: I put this code in Appdelegate didFinishLaunch method. and It is not reflecting any thing. :(

Comment: and what's not working for you? the text color of the status bar or the UIView not showing ??

Comment: I want to change only colour of status bar content. Not even background of status bar. I want exactly same out put as I post picture in my question. First image in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply . Please check out these StackOverflow links to see the best fit for you. My advice is to look more . The status bar is made by default as transparent in iOS 7 so we need to apply these procedures to make it look like it was before iOS 7.

[Status bar and navigation bar issue in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7)

[How to set Status bar background color iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176784/how-to-set-status-bar-background-color-ios-7)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Can You please check question once agin properly. I tried something which is working for If I have navigation bar in my view. But If I set navigation bar hidden it not not working properly. It still shows content of status bar in black colour. So I need solution for that. Other wise If I se t navigation bar then its working fine. Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

instead of:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

`NavigationBar` hidden behavior can be strange if `UIViewController` is child viewController of `UINavigationController`.

Bellow comments are research from @Tyson and @ing0 in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called/19513714#19513714):
For anyone using a UINavigationController:

> The `UINavigationController` does not forward on
>   `preferredStatusBarStyle` calls to its child view controllers. Instead
>   it manages its own state - as it should, it is drawing at the top of
>   the screen where the status bar lives and so should be responsible for
>   it. Therefor implementing `preferredStatusBarStyle` in your VCs within
>   a nav controller will do nothing - they will never be called.
>
> The trick is what the `UINavigationController` uses to decide what to
>   return for `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` or
>   `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`. It bases this on it's
>   `UINavigationBar.barStyle`. The default (`UIBarStyleDefault`) results
>   in the dark foreground `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` status bar. And
>   `UIBarStyleBlack` will give a `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` status
>   bar.
>
> TL;DR:
>
> If you want `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` on a
>   `UINavigationController` use:
>
> ```
> self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
> ```